# Error: A JNI error has occurred (javax.mail.jar)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to read gmail messages using showmsg.java in the javamail sample package, and I keep getting this error when I run it. The program compiles fine though.

Here's the error message:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/ParseException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.ParseException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.event.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

/*
 * Demo app that exercises the Message interfaces.
 * Show information about and contents of messages.
 *
 * @author John Mani
 * @author Bill Shannon
 */

public class msgshow {

    static String protocol;
    static String host = null;
    static String user = null;
    static String password = null;
    static String mbox = null;
    static String url = null;
    static int port = -1;
    static boolean verbose = false;
    static boolean debug = false;
    static boolean showStructure = false;
    static boolean showMessage = false;
    static boolean showAlert = false;
    static boolean saveAttachments = false;
    static int attnum = 1;

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        int optind;
        InputStream msgStream = System.in;

        for (optind = 0; optind < argv.length; optind++) {
            if (argv[optind].equals("-T")) {
                protocol = argv[++optind];
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-H")) {
                host = argv[++optind];
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-U")) {
                user = argv[++optind];
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-P")) {
                password = argv[++optind];
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-v")) {
                verbose = true;
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-D")) {
                debug = true;
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-f")) {
                mbox = argv[++optind];
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-L")) {
                url = argv[++optind];
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-p")) {
                port = Integer.parseInt(argv[++optind]);
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-s")) {
                showStructure = true;
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-S")) {
                saveAttachments = true;
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-m")) {
                showMessage = true;
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("-a")) {
                showAlert = true;
            } else if (argv[optind].equals("--")) {
                optind++;
                break;
            } else if (argv[optind].startsWith("-")) {
                System.out.println(
"Usage: msgshow [-L url] [-T protocol] [-H host] [-p port] [-U user]");
                System.out.println(
"\t[-P password] [-f mailbox] [msgnum ...] [-v] [-D] [-s] [-S] [-a]");
                System.out.println(
"or     msgshow -m [-v] [-D] [-s] [-S] [-f msg-file]");
                System.exit(1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            // Get a Properties object
            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            // Get a Session object
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(debug);

            if (showMessage) {
                MimeMessage msg;
                if (mbox != null)
                    msg = new MimeMessage(session,
                        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mbox)));
                else
                    msg = new MimeMessage(session, msgStream);
                dumpPart(msg);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            // Get a Store object
            Store store = null;
            if (url != null) {
                URLName urln = new URLName(url);
                store = session.getStore(urln);
                if (showAlert) {
                    store.addStoreListener(new StoreListener() {
                        public void notification(StoreEvent e) {
                            String s;
                            if (e.getMessageType() == StoreEvent.ALERT)
                                s = "ALERT: ";
                            else
                                s = "NOTICE: ";
                            System.out.println(s + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }
                store.connect();
            } else {
                if (protocol != null)
                    store = session.getStore(protocol);
                else
                    store = session.getStore();

                // Connect
                if (host != null || user != null || password != null)
                    store.connect(host, port, user, password);
                else
                    store.connect();
            }


            // Open the Folder

            Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
            if (folder == null) {
                System.out.println("No default folder");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            if (mbox == null)
                mbox = "INBOX";
            folder = folder.getFolder(mbox);
            if (folder == null) {
                System.out.println("Invalid folder");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            // try to open read/write and if that fails try read-only
            try {
                folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            }
            int totalMessages = folder.getMessageCount();

            if (totalMessages == 0) {
                System.out.println("Empty folder");
                folder.close(false);
                store.close();
                System.exit(1);
            }

            if (verbose) {
                int newMessages = folder.getNewMessageCount();
                System.out.println("Total messages = " + totalMessages);
                System.out.println("New messages = " + newMessages);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            }

            if (optind >= argv.length) {
                // Attributes & Flags for all messages ..
                Message[] msgs = folder.getMessages();

                // Use a suitable FetchProfile
                FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
                fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
                fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS);
                fp.add("X-Mailer");
                folder.fetch(msgs, fp);

                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("--------------------------");
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
                    dumpEnvelope(msgs[i]);
                    // dumpPart(msgs[i]);
                }
            } else {
                while (optind < argv.length) {
                    int msgnum = Integer.parseInt(argv[optind++]);
                    System.out.println("Getting message number: " + msgnum);
                    Message m = null;

                    try {
                        m = folder.getMessage(msgnum);
                        dumpPart(m);
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException iex) {
                        System.out.println("Message number out of range");
                    }
                }
            }

            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops, got exception! " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
        if (p instanceof Message)
            dumpEnvelope((Message)p);

        /** Dump input stream ..

        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        // If "is" is not already buffered, wrap a BufferedInputStream
        // around it.
        if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream))
            is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        int c;
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
            System.out.write(c);

        **/

        String ct = p.getContentType();
        try {
            pr("CONTENT-TYPE: " + (new ContentType(ct)).toString());
        } catch (ParseException pex) {
            pr("BAD CONTENT-TYPE: " + ct);
        }
        String filename = p.getFileName();
        if (filename != null)
            pr("FILENAME: " + filename);

        /*
         * Using isMimeType to determine the content type avoids
         * fetching the actual content data until we need it.
         */
        if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            pr("This is plain text");
            pr("---------------------------");
            if (!showStructure && !saveAttachments)
                System.out.println((String)p.getContent());
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            pr("This is a Multipart");
            pr("---------------------------");
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
            level++;
            int count = mp.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            level--;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
            pr("This is a Nested Message");
            pr("---------------------------");
            level++;
            dumpPart((Part)p.getContent());
            level--;
        } else {
            if (!showStructure && !saveAttachments) {
                /*
                 * If we actually want to see the data, and it's not a
                 * MIME type we know, fetch it and check its Java type.
                 */
                Object o = p.getContent();
                if (o instanceof String) {
                    pr("This is a string");
                    pr("---------------------------");
                    System.out.println((String)o);
                } else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
                    pr("This is just an input stream");
                    pr("---------------------------");
                    InputStream is = (InputStream)o;
                    int c;
                    while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
                        System.out.write(c);
                } else {
                    pr("This is an unknown type");
                    pr("---------------------------");
                    pr(o.toString());
                }
            } else {
                // just a separator
                pr("---------------------------");
            }
        }

        /*
         * If we're saving attachments, write out anything that
         * looks like an attachment into an appropriately named
         * file.  Don't overwrite existing files to prevent
         * mistakes.
         */
        if (saveAttachments && level != 0 && p instanceof MimeBodyPart &&
                !p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            String disp = p.getDisposition();
            // many mailers don't include a Content-Disposition
            if (disp == null || disp.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
                if (filename == null)
                    filename = "Attachment" + attnum++;
                pr("Saving attachment to file " + filename);
                try {
                    File f = new File(filename);
                    if (f.exists())
                        // XXX - could try a series of names
                        throw new IOException("file exists");
                    ((MimeBodyPart)p).saveFile(f);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    pr("Failed to save attachment: " + ex);
                }
                pr("---------------------------");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void dumpEnvelope(Message m) throws Exception {
        pr("This is the message envelope");
        pr("---------------------------");
        Address[] a;
        // FROM
        if ((a = m.getFrom()) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                pr("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
        }

        // REPLY TO
        if ((a = m.getReplyTo()) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                pr("REPLY TO: " + a[j].toString());
        }

        // TO
        if ((a = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                pr("TO: " + a[j].toString());
                InternetAddress ia = (InternetAddress)a[j];
                if (ia.isGroup()) {
                    InternetAddress[] aa = ia.getGroup(false);
                    for (int k = 0; k < aa.length; k++)
                        pr("  GROUP: " + aa[k].toString());
                }
            }
        }

        // SUBJECT
        pr("SUBJECT: " + m.getSubject());

        // DATE
        Date d = m.getSentDate();
        pr("SendDate: " +
            (d != null ? d.toString() : "UNKNOWN"));

        // FLAGS
        Flags flags = m.getFlags();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Flags.Flag[] sf = flags.getSystemFlags(); // get the system flags

        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < sf.length; i++) {
            String s;
            Flags.Flag f = sf[i];
            if (f == Flags.Flag.ANSWERED)
                s = "\\Answered";
            else if (f == Flags.Flag.DELETED)
                s = "\\Deleted";
            else if (f == Flags.Flag.DRAFT)
                s = "\\Draft";
            else if (f == Flags.Flag.FLAGGED)
                s = "\\Flagged";
            else if (f == Flags.Flag.RECENT)
                s = "\\Recent";
            else if (f == Flags.Flag.SEEN)
                s = "\\Seen";
            else
                continue;       // skip it
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(s);
        }

        String[] uf = flags.getUserFlags(); // get the user flag strings
        for (int i = 0; i < uf.length; i++) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(uf[i]);
        }
        pr("FLAGS: " + sb.toString());

        // X-MAILER
        String[] hdrs = m.getHeader("X-Mailer");
        if (hdrs != null)
            pr("X-Mailer: " + hdrs[0]);
        else
            pr("X-Mailer NOT available");
    }

    static String indentStr = "                                               ";
    static int level = 0;

    /**
     * Print a, possibly indented, string.
     */
    public static void pr(String s) {
        if (showStructure)
            System.out.print(indentStr.substring(0, level * 2));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The command I'm using to run is `java msgshow -D -T imaps -H imap.gmail.com -U [USER] -P [PASS]` and the command I'm using to compile it is `javac -cp ".:./:./lib:./lib/*" msgshow.java`. The javax.mail.jar is contained in the lib folder

This is some alternate code that's much shorter and gets the same errors:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import smtp;
import imaps;
//import java.mail.*;
//import com.sun.mail.*;

public class AccessGmail {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                try
                {
                        Properties prop = new Properties();
                        prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File("smtp.properties")));
                        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);

                        String pass = scan.next();

                        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
                        store.connect("smtp.gmail.com","shane.l.gvoice@gmail.com",pass);

                        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
                        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                        int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
                        System.out.println("Message Count: "+messageCount);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
                catch (IOException e){}
                catch(NoSuchProviderException e){}
                catch(MessagingException e){}
        }
}
```

Comment: Post code, don't link code.

Comment: There's a lot of code. 419 lines seems a bit excessive

Comment: That's SO policy. If that's too much code to post then look into how to trim it down to a minimal example. Find more info on how to ask a good question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think I trimmed it down. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Oh wait. I forgot the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not setting the CLASSPATH when you're running the program so it's not finding the javax.mail.jar file:

```
java -cp ".:lib/javax.mail.jar" msgshow -D -T imaps -H imap.gmail.com -U [USER] -P [PASS]
```

Comment: You're a saint.